# jquery validator addMethod code issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the following method which is displaying me the data from the backend in JSON format

```
[{"email":"email@email.com","status":"InActive"}]

$.validator.addMethod("invalidcode", function(value, element) {
        var duplicate = false;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/_com/security/security.cfc?method=checkEmailStatus',
            data:'email='+$("#Reg_Username").val(),
            async: false,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
                var json = JSON.parse(data);
                if (json[0].status == 'InActive') {
                    var duplicate = true;
                    var regInstructionsFooterHTML = $('#checkEmailRegister4InActive').text();
                    $('#reg-modal-footer').html('');
                    $('#reg-modal-footer').html(regInstructionsFooterHTML);
                } else {
                    var duplicate = false;
                }
            }
        });
        console.log(duplicate);
        return duplicate;
    }, "Email is Inactive");
```

now i am using this code at the bottom as like this:

```
Reg_Username: {
                    minlength: 6,
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                    invalidcode:true,
                    newreg:true
                },
```

now it checks for the invalidcode `addmethod` and then `newreg` method, so if the response coming from the backend is `InActive`, it should show **Email is Inactive** else, if someother response is coming like `reg`, it should show another `addmethod` which i might be writing for checking that

but i think my above `addmethod` has some issues which is why it is always returning `false`

Comment: All seems well except `duplicate ` variable scope. You are creating local scope of `duplicate ` inside `success` callback function. Please remove keyword `var` of the variable  `duplicate `  from the `success` method.

Comment: so it will return me false and inactive , two status right

Comment: Why are you not just using the built in `remote` method?